# C -Implementing strcpy() But Segfault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, char, strcpy

I have made a `strcpy()` function
in C, and I am copying words from one array to other not just letters, but when I run it I am getting Segmentation fault what to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcpy1(char *dest[], char source[])
{
    while ((*dest++ = *source++));
}

int main()
{
    char source[3][20] = { "I", "made", "this" };
    char dest[3][20];

    strcpy1(&dest, source);
    
    //printing destination array contents   
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", dest[i][20]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the prototype for your custom `strcpy1` function should be:

  ```
  void strcpy1(char *dest[], char *source[]);
  ```
- the arrays `source` and `dest` are 2D `char` arrays: a very different type from what `strcpy1` expects, which are arrays of pointers. Change the definition to:

  ```
   char *source[4] = { "I", "made", "this" };
   char *dest[4];
  ```
- you should pass the destination array as `dest` instead of `&dest`
- the source array should have a `NULL` pointer terminator: it should be defined with a length of at least 4. Same for the destination array.
- in the print loop `dest[i][20]` refers to a character beyond the end of the `i`-th string. You should just pass the string as `dest[i]`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcpy1(char *dest[], char *source[])
{
    while ((*dest++ = *source++));
}

int main()
{
    char *source[4] = { "I", "made", "this" };
    char *dest[4];

    strcpy1(dest, source);
    
    //printing destination array contents   
    for (int i = 0; dest[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", dest[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is somewhat confusing to name `strcpy1` a function that has very different semantics from the standard function `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` specifier is for strings, eg, a `char*` referring to the first character of a string.

When you pass `dest[i][20]` to the `printf` function, it is not a `char*`.  It is a single `char`, the **21st** `char` (valid indices are `0`-`19`, for a total of 20 elements).

So it is an array-out-of-bounds-index, and also, not a `char*` as `printf` expects.

```
printf("%s\n", dest[i][20]);
```